# Aggregate with multiple lookup and pipeline return only the last element

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I try below code, it's working to lookup value from other collection. But why it only return the last element.

If I omitted the unwind function, It does return all result from the model, but the second lookup will not working as the first lookup return arrays.

My objective is to look up folder that include the model id which represented in `templatefolders` collection.

```
const result = await this.dashboardModel
      .aggregate([{ $match: filter }])
      .lookup({
        from: 'templatefolders',
        as: 'template',
        let: { id: '$_id' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: ['$dashboardId', '$$id'],
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: ['$deletedAt', null],
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              folderId: 1,
            },
          },
        ],
      })
      .unwind('template')
      .lookup({
        from: 'folders',
        as: 'folder',
        let: { folderId: '$template.folderId' },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $expr: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: ['$_id', '$$folderId'],
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: ['$deletedAt', null],
                  },
                ],
              },
            },
          },
          {
            $project: {
              _id: 1,
              name: 1,
            },
          },
        ],
      })
      .unwind('folder')
      .exec();
    return result;
```

Result

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      ...(parent field)
      "template": {
        "_id": "60ab22b03b39e40012b7cc4a",
        "folderId": "60ab080b3b39e40012b7cc41"
      },
      "folder": {
        "_id": "60ab080b3b39e40012b7cc41",
        "name": "Folder 1"
      }
    }
  ],
  "meta": {},
  "success": true,
  "message": "Succesfully get list"
}
```

I came from Front end background. I hope my question is not a silly one.

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
dashboard: [{
  _id: dashboard1
}]

templatefolders: [{
  dashboardId: dashboard1,
  folderId: folder123
}]

folders: [{
  _id: folder123
}]
```

Comment: `$unwind` is deconstructing your array. Check here https://mongoplayground.net/p/8KzJs1EneYe You have an array, but unwind make it as 3 objects. So when you do unwind, you will get objects, so the result of unwind will be changed. Based on the previous stage, you need to write query.

Comment: Here, without sample data, we can't tell you anything. If u need, please edit the question and update with sample data which should only have necessary fields.

Comment: @varman how you return the result as an array with all element again?

Comment: You need to use `$group` which helps to group the object again

Comment: @varman I added some sample data. is that enough? what I want to achieve is to get folder object when accessing dashboard collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$lookup` to join collections

- `$lookup` to join two collections .[Lookup doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/)
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array. [Unwind doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)
- `$group` to reconstruct the array which we already deconstructed [Group doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/)

Here is the code

```
db.dashboard.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "templatefolders",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "dashboardId",
      "as": "joinDashboard"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$joinDashboard"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "folders",
      "localField": "joinDashboard.folderId",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "joinDashboard.joinFolder"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "joinDashboard": {
        "$push": "$joinDashboard"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VrGSvF65LgZ)**

Comment: Group are needed if we want to summarize a field right? I don't think I need that for this process though

Comment: WHen you unwind an array, its beign deconstrted. If you need to reconstruct, u need to group it. Otherwise it will give some dupicates entries. But it dependd on your requirement!!